# V4l2 - program and camera freeze while dequeing a buffer

Tags: c, camera, v4l2

I'm new into V4l2 thing and I'd like to capture some pictures from my camera. I found a snippet of code in C on the internet which looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/v4l2-common.h>
#include <linux/v4l2-controls.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    // 1. Open the device
    int fd = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("Failed to open device.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // 2. Ask the device if it can capture frames
    struct v4l2_capability capability;
    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, &capability) < 0) {
        perror("Failed to get device capabilities, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // 3. Set image format
    struct v4l2_format imageFormat;
    imageFormat.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    imageFormat.fmt.pix.width = 1920;
    imageFormat.fmt.pix.height = 1080;
    imageFormat.fmt.pix.pixelformat - V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
    imageFormat.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE;
    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &imageFormat) < 0) {
        perror("Device couldn't set format, VIDIOC_S_FMT.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // 4. Request buffers from the device
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers requestBuffer = {0};
    requestBuffer.count = 1;
    requestBuffer.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    requestBuffer.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;

    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, &requestBuffer) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't request buffer from device, VIDIOC_REQBUFS.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // 5. Query the buffer to get raw data ie. ask for the requested buffer
    // and allocate memory for it
    struct v4l2_buffer queryBuffer = {0};
    queryBuffer.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    queryBuffer.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    queryBuffer.index = 0;
    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &queryBuffer) < 0) {
        perror("Device did not return the buffer information, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char* buffer = (char*)mmap(NULL, queryBuffer.length, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, queryBuffer.m.offset);
    memset(buffer, 0, queryBuffer.length);

    // 6. Get a frame
    struct v4l2_buffer bufferInfo;
    memset(&bufferInfo, 0, sizeof(bufferInfo));
    bufferInfo.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    bufferInfo.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
    bufferInfo.index = 0;

    // Activate streaming
    int type = bufferInfo.type;
    if (ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMON, &type) < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't start streaming, VIDIOC_STREAMON.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Queue the buffer
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QBUF, &bufferInfo) < 0){
        perror("Could not queue buffer, VIDIOC_QBUF");
        return 1;
    }

    // Dequeue the buffer
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &bufferInfo) < 0){
        perror("Could not dequeue the buffer, VIDIOC_DQBUF");
        return 1;
    }

    // Frames get written after dequeuing the buffer

    printf("Buffer has %f KB of data.\n", (double)bufferInfo.bytesused / 1024);

    // Write the data out to file
    int outfile = open("webcam_output.jpeg", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);

    int bufPos = 0, outFileMemBlockSize = 0;  // the position in the buffer and the amoun to copy from
                                    // the buffer
    int remainingBufferSize = bufferInfo.bytesused; // the remaining buffer size, is decremented by
                                                // memBlockSize amount on each loop so we do not overwrite the buffer
    char* outFileMemBlock = NULL;  // a pointer to a new memory block
    int itr = 0; // counts thenumber of iterations
    while(remainingBufferSize > 0) {
        bufPos += outFileMemBlockSize;  // increment the buffer pointer on each loop
                                    // initialise bufPos before outFileMemBlockSize so we can start
                                    // at the begining of the buffer

        outFileMemBlockSize = 1024;    // set the output block size to a preferable size. 1024 :)
        outFileMemBlock = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * outFileMemBlockSize);

        // copy 1024 bytes of data starting from buffer+bufPos
        memcpy(outFileMemBlock, buffer+bufPos, outFileMemBlockSize);
        write(outfile, outFileMemBlock,outFileMemBlockSize);

        // calculate the amount of memory left to read
        // if the memory block size is greater than the remaining
        // amount of data we have to copy
        if(outFileMemBlockSize > remainingBufferSize)
            outFileMemBlockSize = remainingBufferSize;

        // subtract the amount of data we have to copy
        // from the remaining buffer size
        remainingBufferSize -= outFileMemBlockSize;

        // display the remaining buffer size
        //cout << itr++ << " Remaining bytes: "<< remainingBufferSize << endl;
    
        free(outFileMemBlock);
    }

    // Close the file
    close(outfile);
    printf("Image saved!\n");

    // end streaming
    if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF, &type) < 0){
        perror("Couldn't end streaming, VIDIOC_STREAMOFF");
        close(fd);
        return 1;
    }

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine when I run it, it takes a photo and saves it as .jpeg. But after several times of running this programm (sometimes even at the first time since plugging the camera in) it freezes at the `ioctl()` function in which the buffer is dequeued, this is the part of code:

```
// Dequeue the buffer
if(ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_DQBUF, &bufferInfo) < 0){
    perror("Could not dequeue the buffer, VIDIOC_DQBUF");
    return 1;
}
```

It just doesn't respond and the console lags, I can write input but it doesn't change anything. After exiting the process with Ctrl+C, when I run it again the same thing happens. The only solution I managed to find is unplug and plug the camera again. Then it works again for a few tries, but after that the whole thing repeats. My question is why does it happen and how can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If it'd help, I can give my camera name - it's "A4Tech Co., Ltd. A4tech FHD 1080P PC Camera"